# Parameter inside sql query where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, parameters, pentaho

i'll run a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE datasource_detail = '{"datasource_detail":[{"db_name":"database_temp","port":"3306","db_username":"root","host":"localhost","tab1":"table1","tab2":"table2"}]}'
```

but there is a require to get parameter

i try this but didnt work well

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE datasource_detail = '{"datasource_detail":[{"db_name":"database_temp","port":"3306","db_username":"root","host":"localhost","tab1":"'${tab1}'","tab2":"'${tab2}'"}]}'
```

someone help me pls?

oh , i run this query in pentaho data integration: input table

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should try to put the compared value in a @Variable

```
Declare @Compared_Value nvarchar(500);
Set @Compared_Value = '{"datasource_detail":[{"db_name":"database_temp","port":"3306","db_username":"root","host":"localhost","tab1":"'${tab1}'","tab2":"'${tab2}'"}]}'

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE datasource_detail = @Compared_Value
```

In case a part of your compared value is dynamic, you should build up your compared value with a CONCAT-statement
Set @Compared_Value = CONCATE(part1, part 2,...)